# Declaring two or more types for a public class variable in c++

Tags: c++, class, types

**Note:** I am using C++11

---

Suppose that I have a class `foo` with public variable `bar` which can be either a float or an int. The type of `bar` is determined upon assignment like so:

```
foo object_name;
object_name.weight() = value
```

if `value` is an int, then `object_name.weight()` is an int, if `value` is a float, then `object_name.weight()` is a float.

One possibility is to have two classes `foo_i` and `foo_f` with `bar` typed as int and float, respectively; but this is rather inconvenient, especially when `foo_i` and `foo_f` are basically clones of one another with only the type difference between them.

Is there a way to specify the type of `bar` as either `int` or `float` within the scope of a single class?

Comment: If you are able to use C++17 or later, you may use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: @RSahu I only have C++14 and earlier. I've been using C++11 thus far.

Comment: The simplest way that comes to the top of my head is to template class foo on type of bar, i.e. ```template<typename TBar> class foo { public: TBar bar; };``` . This way, you write the class body only once, and then can use ```typedef foo<int> foo_i;``` and ```typedef foo<float> foo_f;``` to get your two classes.

Comment: You may want to roll your version of `std::variant`. It's an abstraction that makes sense and you can use it for your use case.

Comment: (I'll expand my comment into an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write the class body only once, you can template the class `foo` on the type of `bar`, and then use two *typedefs* to simplify subsequent usage. Example:

```
template<typename TBar> class foo { 
    public: TBar bar; 
}; 

typedef foo<int> foo_i; 
typedef foo<float> foo_f;
```

Of note for those new to C++ is that this metaprogramming technique will literally make the compiler generate two separate versions of the same class, i.e., from the perspective of the generated binary, it is equivalent to writing the class body twice with two different types for `bar`.

Comment: Since `foo_i` and `foo_f` are not declared, can I get away with just the template and class declaration?

Comment: @R.Burton, short answer: usually yes. If the code above is in a header and the client code using foo_i and foo_f includes this header, then you can think of ```foo_i``` and ```foo_f``` aliases as automatically being substituted by ```foo<int>``` and ```foo<float>```. In this case, the compiler rolls out the templated class bodies for both types, i.e. you can think of them as both being declared in this very same header.

Comment: The only time you'd have to worry about this is if you don't have the full code for templated class ```foo``` available to the client code. In this case, you'd still need to forward-declare the templated class, and make that declaration available. However, you can hide away the implementation / definition (everything within the ```{}```) in some inaccessible header (or protect it from being instantiated with the ```extern template``` declaration), and then explicitly instantiate the template in another source file.

Comment: This latter method makes sense when you're writing C++ libraries and trying to reduce client code compile time. For more info, see docs on ```template class ...``` and ```extern template class``` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template.